# Delete all characters up to and including a character in a file name using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to delete all characters up to and including the first `-` character in the filenames in a directory using PowerShell. An example file name is: `batch orders October 17 - 16278856 - all orders October 17-18.pdf`

I just want to delete everyting up through the first -, so the name above would be changed to: `16278856 - all orders October 17-18.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to actually rename the files you could do something like  (using earlier answer for search)

```
foreach ($file in (get-childitem *.pdf).name) {
    Rename-Item $file ($file -replace '^[^-]*-\s*')
}
```

FYI this only works in the current directory you're in...

What is this doing?

**Foreach**

This is a loop. the **$file** is just a variable, can be whatever - must start with **$**

The **(get-childitem *.pdf).name)** just get's a list of all file names including the extension in the current folder and it will be put in **$file**

the loop will work through each name, one at a time

**Rename-Item** just renames files and must be followed by "what to rename" then "the name to make it"

inside here, **$file** is just each file name

**($file -replace '^[^-]*-\s*')** just tells it the new name, which is itself minus the beginning.

in regex the first **^** stands for the beginning of the line. then the **[^-]** means anything BUT a hyphen and finally ***** means repeat that character search till it finds a different character(which would be a hyphen). then **-\s*** means a hyphen followed by whitespace.

The **{}** brackets are there to define the foreach loop's script which it must loop through.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Comment: The regex credit goes to [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) ... But i saw you were confused on deleting. I'd recommend [learn powershell in a month of lunches](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CRTahGYnws&list=PL6D474E721138865A) on youtube. There are better more complete options on sites like pluralsight or cbt nuggets or itpro.tv, but we can't all have those.  Udemy may offer something much cheaper than the former options

Comment: Yeah, when I was using -replace prior to your advice it just seemed to be creating an alias. I may give it a dive, it wasn't for me and I don't currently use it, my brother in law gets a lot of work files on a laptop running Windows and he wanted a simple way to just copy and paste each time to fix it, thanks again for your assistance. Thanks for the link! I prefer learning through books though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-replace` operator.

```
'foo - bar - baz.pdf' -replace '^[^-]*-\s*'
```

`^` matches the beginning of a string. `[^-]*` matches any number of consecutive characters that are not hyphens. `-\s*` matches a literal hyphen followed by any number of whitespace characters.

Calling `-replace` without a replacement value removes the matched substring.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah, I had found that one in the docs but it doesn't also delete the - just all the characters up to it, also, I need to do it for every file in the directory, I've tried to use the Get-Childitem *.pdf but to no avail. I dont knw ant powershell, I'm sure it'd be simple if I did

Comment: @user2943472 *"but it doesn't also delete the - just all the characters up to it"* Now it does.